# Two-port network

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework, kirchhoffs-laws, network

I have been trying to solve a problem on two-port network but I am getting two different answers:

APPROACH 1:

In the problem the Y-Parameter is given so I converted Y parameters to H parameters and substituted \$I_2=-0.01V_2\$ and then tried to calculate voltage gain but I am getting $$\frac{-s}{0.9+10.1s}$$

Conversion is as follows:

[image]

APPROACH 2:

I expanded the Y-Parameter to its equations in Terms of \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ and substituted \$I_2=-0.01V_2\$ and the answer came out to be $$\frac{-s}{1+10s}$$

[image]

So my question is which one is correct?

Comment: please edit the title so that it describes the problem

Comment: You should show how you have converted the y-parameters into h-parameters. Only then we can see if there are any errors in your manipulation.

Comment: @LvW Okay I have updated the question

Comment: S is the unit of measure Siemens=mho.  Where does your s come from?

Comment: @Franc here S is just a variable, not unit

Comment: @Preet  y11= i1/ v1  (unit S) calculated for v2=0V;  y12= i1/v2  (unit S) calculated with v1=0V;  y21= i2/v1 (unit S) calculated with v2=0; y22=i2/v2  (unit S) mantaining v1=0.

Comment: @Franc okay that I know but here we are only taking it as a variable, you may take it as 'x' is you want.

Comment: @Franc, *s* is the usual symbol for the variable when using the Laplace transform.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify, I transformed the Y parameters into Z parameters and calculated the voltage gain as follows:
[image]